# Drag and Drop isn't working on Safari iOS (iPad)?

Tags: ios, ipad, drag

according to the browser_compatibility section below, DragEvent is not supported on Safari iOS (iPad). Does this mean you cannot implement Drag and Drop like File drop?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent#browser_compatibility

Comment: It _may_ be that Mozilla's page is a bit out of date (https://caniuse.com/dragndrop for example says it works on iOS 15 and up). May be worth a test if you can use it on newer iOS versions.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks for sharing the page. actually, I already test with the newest iOS version and it doesn't work... .   I noticed that dragEvent seems not supported    https://caniuse.com/?search=dragEvent